# Prove $c \lambda+ k$ is an eigenvalue for $cA + kIn$ and $x$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $c \lambda + k$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix and $\lambda$ a particular eigenvalue of $A$ with $x$ an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$. prove that for any scalars $c$ and $k$, $c\lambda + k$ is an eigenvalue for $cA + kIn$ and $x$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $ c \lambda + k$.

I think I may have an idea of how to show this proof but I'm not sure how to express it. I kind of want to write $Ax = \lambda x$, multiply $(cA + kIn)$ by $x$ all the way through, then replace $A$ with $\lambda$, then factor $c \lambda + k$ out, since that follows a similar example my teacher did. but this seems to make not much of an explanation to me, it seems like all that does is show that matrices are commutative.

So is my method correct? if not, can someone explain in detail or show me the correct method? And if it is, can someone explain how this actually proves it?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: You have asked 98 questions, it's time for you to learn to write in latex

Comment: im sorry, Ive tried searching for codes on certain hard symbols a few times before, but either I couldn't find em or they didn't work, and ive had almost all of those questions come from this 1 subject, and had barely even time to eat. :( I can see the \lamda symbol is pretty easy though. I'll try to do everything in latex from now on. I also broke my laptop leaving 5 keys so far broken, and I'm already spending even more time ctrl + H 'ing all my letters >.<

Comment: @JL `\lambda` $=\lambda$, `\times` $=\times$, `\mathbf x` $=\mathbf x$, `A_{n+1}` $=A_{n+1}$, `\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 3 \end{bmatrix}` $= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$, etc.  Look at the links I posted (especially the first one) for more information.

Comment: thankyou! I have started right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A\mathbf x = \lambda\mathbf x \implies cA\mathbf x =c\lambda \mathbf x$

Note that $kI_n \mathbf x = k\mathbf x$ so add this to the above equation to get:

$cA\mathbf x + kI_n \mathbf x = c\lambda \mathbf x + k\mathbf x \iff (cA + kI_n) \mathbf x = (c\lambda  + k)\mathbf x$

Therefore, $c\lambda +k$ is an eigenvalue of $cA + kI_n$ corresponding to eigenvector $\mathbf x$.  $\square$